# Tinkerpop common version for multiple databases

Tags: neo4j, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph, gremlin-server

**Summary**

I am devloping a app that is intendent to work across multiple graph databases suppoted by tinkerpop

**Details**

Based on my research the same version of tinkerpop library (gremlin-python) does not work with the latest version of all the graph databases. What is the best approach for this situation. The databases I intent to test are

1. JanusGraph 0.2.0 supported gremlin-python 3.2.7
2. NEO4J 3.3.3 supported gremlin-python 3.3.2

I am still trying to integrating some more databases like orientDB and Amazon Neptune do you know what version they will supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue can be a little tricky especially with non-open source systems that don't publish version and feature support clearly. For open source systems, you can typically find the version of TinkerPop they support for a particular version by looking at the pom.xml of the project. For OrientDB that means finding the version you want (in this case 3.2.3.0) and then looking for the gremlin-core dependency:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/blob/3.2.3.0/driver/pom.xml#L47

The version points to a property, so examine the pom a bit further and you'll see that number defined above:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/blob/3.2.3.0/driver/pom.xml#L14

So OrientDB 3.2.3.0 supports TinkerPop 3.2.3. With closed source systems you can only search around until you find the answer your looking for or ask the vendor directly I guess - I've seen that Neptune is on 3.3.x, but I'm not sure of what version of "x".

Just because all of these systems support different versions of TinkerPop and the general recommendation is to use a matching TinkerPop version to connect to them doesn't mean that you can't get a 3.3.x driver to connect to a 3.2.x based server. You may not have the best experience doing so and you would need to be aware of a few things as you do that, but I think it can be done.

The key to this to work from a driver perspective is to ensure that you have the right serialization configuration for the graph you are connecting to. This is true whether you are trying to connect to a same version system or not. By default, TinkerPop ensures that these configurations within the same version are aligned so that they work out of the box. This is why we tend to recommend that you use the same version when possible. When not possible, you need to make those alignments manually.

For example, if you scroll down in this link a bit to the "Serialization" section you will find the supported formats for Neptune:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html

As long as you configure your driver to match one of those formats it should work for you. The same could be said of JanusGraph, which in contrast to Neptune, will not support Gryo or GraphSON 3.0 as it is bound to the 3.2.x line.  The configuration for the serializers can be found in JanusGraph's packaging of Gremlin Server:

https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/v0.2.0/janusgraph-dist/src/assembly/static/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml#L15-L21

As to how you configure your python driver for serialization? Admittedly, there isn't a lot written on that. The key is to set the `message_serializer` when configuring the `Client` (from gremlinpython 3.3.2):

https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.3.2/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/driver/client.py#L44-L45

You can see there that by default it is set to GraphSON 3.0. So, that's perfect for Neptune, but not JanusGraph. For JanusGraph, which doesn't support GraphSON 3.0 yet, you would just change the configuration to use the GraphSON 2.0 serializer:

https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.3.2/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/driver/serializer.py#L149

So, that is just getting a connection working - then there are other things to consider:

1. If you use a new version of gremlinpython against an older server, you will need to make sure that you are aware of any features that aren't supported on the server (e.g. don't use `math()` step from your 3.3.x client because it won't work on a 3.2.x server)
2. CosmosDB has may allow you to connect with 3.3.x, but it doesn't have full Gremlin support and at this time does not support bytecode based traversals - only strings
3. A number of bugs have been fixed in GraphSON serialization over these releases and sometimes certain types may have a revised serialization scheme that may prevent a 3.3.x from talking to a 3.2.x - I can't think of any big issues like that offhand that would immediately jump out, but I'm pretty sure it's happened - perhaps something in serialization of `Tree` and perhaps some of the extended types. You can always look at the full list of GraphSON types [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/dev/io/) and compare between published versions if you run into trouble.

Comment: Ya, I will look into this...Great explanation